# Why is crossing paths bad in Traveling Salesman?

Tags: np-hard, np, traveling-salesman

I'm learning about Traveling Salesman in an online course (sorry I can't share the link it's paid only) and the first step to solving it then just state "as a heuristic we avoid crossed paths" and never really explained why. Why are crossed paths bad in traveling salesman?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is for *Euclidean TSP* only, and as you mention yourself, it is only used as a heuristic.

But try to create an example yourself and see what happens when you have crossing links as part of your solution:

[image: Crossing E-TSP]

From [Urban OR](https://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter6/6.4.7.html):

**Property 1:** The optimum traveling salesman tour does not intersect itself.

Comment: If dist(a, b) + dist(c,d) < dist(a, c) + dist(b, d) then an optimal tour cannot connect both a,c and b,d. No matter how distances are defined. For Euclidean distance “no crossing paths” follows. For distances on a 2d map with obstacles crossing lines might be optimal, for example if there is an obstacle between a and b, and another between c and d, and crossing lines avoids both obstacles.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't follow, did I say anything wrong?